# foreach() variable arrays within variable array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

How can I retrieve all of the values from variable arrays within a variable array?

**EDIT:** I most likely don't know how to explain it well, but I want to know how I can display the values in `$oranges` and `$melon` within `$variables`. I thought it would be as simple as setting variables and placing them into an array but it returns "Array".

**Example:**

```
<?php 
$oranges = array("0","1");
$melon = array("2","3");


  $variables = array($oranges,$melon);
  $i = 1;


 foreach ($variables as $var) {
 $name = "txt".$i;
 echo "<input type='text' name='".$name."' value='".$var."' />";
 $i++;
 echo "<input type='file' name='image'>";

 } 


 ?>
```

Comment: what ?? sometimes i am asking myself : am i tired or questions are "non qualified questions" ?? ;) Please specify more what you are trying to do and the result expected

Comment: What are you expecting as result? It will help us to understand...

Comment: Please, explain, what output do you want to get. What is $name?

Comment: I like that you edited your comment to a more courteous one lol

Comment: Please see my EDIT. That should clear things up.

Comment: @JosanIracheta What is $name in foreach? `name='".$name."' `

Comment: $name is just there to name the input. What I want to do is show the values of $oranges and $melon. Right now it shows "Array", "Array". I want it to show "0","1","2","3".

Comment: Maybe you could [merge](http://us1.php.net/array_merge) the two arrays into one array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieving values of an array within another equals to retrieve a value from one single array. You just have to know what you want to do.

Suppose we have array `$A` and array `$A1` and `$A2` inside `$A`.  `foreach ($A as $innerArray) ...` `$innerArray` the first inner array for the first loop, then the second etc ... If you want to get `$innerArray` values, make another loop, or get them directly if you already know the keys.

**Exemple :**
here are your vars:

```
$oranges = array("0","1");
$melon = array("2","3");

$variables = array($oranges,$melon);
```

**Retrieve value of single array**

```
echo $oranges[0]; // prints 0
echo $melon[1]; // prints 3
```

**Retrieve values from array within another**

```
foreach ($variables as $var) {
 $name = "txt".$i;
 echo "<input type='text' name='".$name."' value='".$var["INDEX"]."' />"; // INDEX must be an existing key in $oranges or $melon
 $i++;
 echo "<input type='file' name='image'>";

 }
```

Comment: Your first sentence made it click for me. I added two `input` elements and gave them the following values: `$var[0]` & `$var[1]`. You rock bro.

Answer (score 1):

According to your code

```
$oranges = array("zero","one");
$melon = array("two","three");
$variables = array($oranges,$melon);
$i = 1;


 foreach ($variables as $var) {

     // $var[0] will contain "zero"
     // $var[1] will contain "one"

     //When $i increments to 2 on the next loop
     // $var[0] will contain "two"
     // $var[1] will contain "three"
 }
```

If you want to access these values without a loop, it is as simple as

```
$variables[0][0] --->  "zero"
$variables[0][1] --->  "one"
$variables[1][0] --->  "two"
$variables[1][1] --->  "three"
```

Comment: This is very good stuff. Kinda confusing for me at first, but it all makes sense now. Thank you :)